# Light comes out much brighter when rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

I want the fire in the upper pillar to look like it does in the unrendered image, but as you can see on the pic it's just super bright. I'm rendering in cycles, and the fire is a material I downloaded. The fire in the lower candlestick is looking like it should, anyone have an idea of what I might do? 
thanks!
(I know the whole thing is super dark right now, that's about to change)

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the .blend? I would like to work with this.

Comment: Do you have something hidden in your scene but still set to render?

Comment: ohhh yes I had a light source there I'd hidden and forgotten about, thank you Chris!

Answer (score 1):

I had a hidden light source where the fire is, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you select all the objects in the scene and press W, and go to clear all restrict blender. It could work.

Comment: Seems like I only go through the different select-options when I press W, but it's good to know that this is an option for other things as well. Do you know where I can find that option from the menu?

Comment: i have no idea at all

Answer (score 0):

you should be seeing this if you are selecting all objects and pressing w in the scene. What are you seeing? maybe post a picture of what you see, so I can help.

[image]